# Setting a while loop in python to take unknown number of variables

Tags: python, dictionary, args

**Spoiler** This is related to Hackerrank's 30 days of Code. I'm using python 2.

I'm having a problem figuring out part of the Day 8 (Dictionaries and Maps) challenge. Basically, they want to feed you x number of names and numbers so you can build a dictionary. Afterwards they feed you n number of queries so you can call them in the phonebook if they're there or print "not found" if otherwise. But n is an unknown number, hence why I'm lost.
Problem statement [here](https://hackerrank-challenge-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/17161-30-dictionaries-and-maps-English?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1462660568&Signature=XOaVhzIEycz6CpY9W%2Flyom%2F2g6k%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D30-dictionaries-and-maps-English.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf) in case anyone is interested...

Anyways, I pass the prelim test case with my code but only 1 of the actual 7 cases because I have no idea what range to put in my "while" loop (so I put something arbitrary like 1000.) I have a feeling like I'll have to use something like *args but I have no idea how to splice it in. Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
t = int(raw_input())
phonebook = {}
for x in range(t):                                
    entry,num = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
    entry,num = [str(entry),int(num)]
    phonebook[entry] = num
i = 0
while i < unknown_range:                    <---- problem here
    name = str(raw_input())
    if name in phonebook.keys():
        string = name +'='+ str(phonebook[name])
        print(string)
        i += 1
    else:
        print("Not found")
        i += 1
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to know how many queries there are. Just keep going until the end.

Comment: You don't need to use `str` on `raw_input`, since it always returns a string.

Comment: The instructions say _"continue reading lines until there is no more input"_, implying reading from a file. But you're reading from stdin, so the input doesn't usually end. Hit `ctrl + D` to emulate hitting the end of the file, and catch the resulting `EOFError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a loop where the exit condition is given in the loop itself:

```
i = 0
while True:
    name = str(raw_input())
    # or a try-except statement depending on the kind of input
    if not name.strip():
        break
    if name in phonebook.keys():
        string = name +'='+ str(phonebook[name])
        print(string)
        i += 1
    else:
        print("Not found")
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You basically set it up exactly the way I was thinking about it but alas, it was still too clunky for the practice challenge. I finally gave up and looked at the editorial and the author used "lines = sys.stdin.readlines()" to read the queries. I'm pretty new to this so I didn't even know about this method, so... lesson learned